# Server Signature off not working on .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working hardly to improve my website rank in SEO.I have done many and i have improved from C grade to B grade ,But from morning onwards i have been trying out 2 things .

```
  1.IP CANONICALIZATION 
  2.TURN OFF SERVER SIGNATURE
```

i have added the following to turn off the server signature to my .htaccess under public_html folder

```
 #Turn Off sserver signature
 ServerSignature Off
```

For Ip canonicalization ,thec code i have included to the .htaccess is

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx\.xx\.xxx\.xxx [nc,or]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [nc]
 RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

both of them are not working as i have checked it through a SEO analyzing tool http://www.seositecheckup.com/ ,but another SEO analyzing tool http://www.woorank.com/ saying that both are working

Do any would say which one that can i trust ,what i am doing wrong in code

Comment: Make sure if your `.htaccess` is enabled by putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: @anubhava i have done it .Thank you

Comment: Are you seeing 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: @anubhava yes it is generating 500 internal error.

Comment: OK can you check your error.log to see what the error is?

Comment: @anubhava sorry ,i dont know how to check error.log

Comment: @anubhava i have checked error_log file under public_html,but there are only some systax errors .Thank you

Comment: Apache error.log is usually under /etc or /var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Apache 
ServerTokens is only for **server config** not `.htaccess` which means you can only change them via `httpd.conf` file.

```
Description:    Configures the Server HTTP response header
Syntax:         ServerTokens Major|Minor|Min[imal]|Prod[uctOnly]|OS|Full
Default:        ServerTokens Full
Context:        server config
Status:         Core
Module:         core
```

[Server Token](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#servertokens)

Comment: Please note that ServerToken and ServerSignature aren't the same.