# Modify server configs while deploying Laravel app to AWS ECS using jenkins

Tags: apache, jenkins, laravel-5, http-headers, amazon-ecs

My Laravel app response header contains server information and I want to get rid of it. I tried adding .htacess file to app root but it didn't workout. How can I change server configs while I am deploying through jenkins.

.htacess file

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

[Response Header with server information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEJkq.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server Signature off not working on .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348862/server-signature-off-not-working-on-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue nothing worked for me. I then tried the following procedure and it worked

select you app image and go to configurations

under build tab create/update file with the name

> $WORKSPACE/apache/security.conf

and add the following content

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
Header set X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff"
TraceEnable Off
```

to add some apache ifmodule do it same but with filename

> $WORKSPACE/apache/headers.conf

final step, append your post-build actions with

```
COPY apache/security.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf

RUN a2enmod headers rewrite
```

I hope this works for you.